# YamlDotNet: How to customize deserializer to handle same key with different type of value

Tags: yaml, yamldotnet

config.yaml:

```
App1:
  settings:
    redirectUrl: http://www.test.com
App2:
  settings:
    redirectUrl:
      test: http://www.test.com
      prod: http://www.prod.com
```

C# objects

```
public class Config
 {
    public Dictionary<string, App> Apps { get; set; }
 }

public class App
 {
    public Dictionary<string, Setting> Settings { get; set; }
 }

public class Setting
 {
    public string Test {get;set;}
    public string Prod {get;set;}
 }
```

Expected result:

for `App1`, both `test` and `prod` are the same http://www.test.com

for `App2`, `test` is `http://www.test.com` and `prod` is http://www.prod.com

I have done a lot of research but cannot figure out how to achieve this by using custom deserializer. 
Please help..

Answer (score 2):

You could make your `Settings` class implement `IYamlConvertible`. That interface allows you to control the serialization process. A possible implementation could be:

```cs
public class SettingsBase
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public string Prod { get; set; }
}

public class Setting : SettingsBase, IYamlConvertible
{
    public void Read(IParser parser, Type type, ObjectDeserializer nestedObjectDeserializer)
    {
        var scalar = parser.Allow<Scalar>();
        if (scalar != null)
        {
            Test = Prod = scalar.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            var values = (SettingsBase)nestedObjectDeserializer(typeof(SettingsBase));
            this.Test = values.Test;
            this.Prod = values.Prod;
        }
    }
    
    public void Write(IEmitter emitter, ObjectSerializer nestedObjectSerializer)
    {
        if (Test == Prod)
        {
            nestedObjectSerializer(Test);
        }
        else
        {
            nestedObjectSerializer(new SettingsBase { Test = this.Test, Prod = this.Prod });
        }
    }
}
```

Here I've used a base class (`SettingsBase`) as a way to easily (de)serialize the properties, but one could use another strategy. Basically the `Read` method checks if the current token is a scalar. If so, it uses its value. Otherwise, it deserializes as a `SettingsBase`. The `Write` method does the opposite.

[A fully working example is available here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bKSI7d)